# Android - Change drawable dynamically using Java at runtime

Tags: java, android, drawable

I would like to be able to change the value of `android:background` using Java at any given time. This is how I set up my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg</item>
</style>
```

Ultimately, I would like to be able to pull an image from the `assets` folder and use it as a background at runtime.

**EDIT**

I don't have any Java code that attempts to do this so far. What I'm looking for is an approach. I'm new to Android, so sometimes I don't even know where to start :-(.

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: `I am not sure if I am doing it right.` - doing what exactly? show your current code

Comment: Hi Marcin, sorry that was a bit vague. I don't have any Java code that attempts to do this so far. I actually don't know where to start.